# Starting search from rightmost column and moving left pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm very new to pandas and I'm trying to implement the code to search for something on an excel spreadsheet.

Basically, the most recent price can be found on the furthest right column named `"final cost"`, and that's what I need. However, there are multiple columns named `"final cost"` (as every invoice is posted on there).

**What I currently have:**

```
def find_most_recent(row_num: int, df) -> float:
    k = -1
    checker = False
    while not checker:
        if df.columns[k] == "final cost":
            if not pd.isnull(df.iloc[row_num, k]):
                checker = True
                return df.loc[row_num, df.columns[k]]
        k -= 1
```

where `row_num` is the current row that is being searched, and `df` is the current dataframe being searched.

However, this gets only the first encounter of `"final cost"`. For example, on a dataset of:

[image]

I want the return to be one of the prices in `column L`, but I'm getting returns of values from `column F` instead.

Any suggestions of a method to use?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, putting

```
if "final cost" in df.columns[k]:
```

instead of

```
if df.columns[k] = "final cost":
```

seemed to have fix it

Comment: Best possible route for an answer!

Comment: Also, nicely written function.